# No entry grey screen with spinner with new SSD

Tags: hardware, ssd, disk-utility, recovery

My hard drive bit the dust rather spectacularly on my 2011 15" MBP. Luckily, I have a model without torx screws, so I popped it open, put in a 240 GB SSD I had lying around, and did and Internet boot into Lion recovery.

I used Disk Utility to format the drive, one partition, Mac OS extended, encrypted. It downloaded Lion, but after that first reboot, I've got a grey screen with a no entry sign and a spinner. It's not changed for 20 minutes.

Is there anything I can do? Is it not possible to us an SSD? I have other hard drives. Was encryption the mistake?

Comment: Could you edit this? OS X encryption options depend on OS version.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this from my working OS! The problem was with selecting encryption when formatting the drive. I reformatted without, painstakingly downloaded Lion again and all seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

That means that the computer can't find a boot image.

Power off and then boot with option held down. If any bootable volumes are connected, you can choose them.

If no bootable volumes are connected, make one (internet recovery or use another Mac) and then connect it.

Comment: From what I can gather, encrypting the volume definitely causes this. Redownloading Lion, will update on progress when it's done!

Comment: @fredley File vault still leaves a bootable volume - so encryption setup  went majorly wrong or there is a hardware error if you get the "no entry" symbol any time after enabling file vault.

Comment: I didn't use file vault, I selected encryption at format time. Other answers on here seem to confirm that this option is not suitable for bootable volumes.